# Loading of datatemplate on a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

I have created a datatemplate and using it as a resource on a listbox, but the listbox isn't showing up my data template.
Here is the code for datatemplate definition

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template1">
        <Canvas Height="40" Width="850">
            <TextBlock Height="40" Width="40" Canvas.Top="10" Foreground="Aqua">
            </TextBlock>

            <Label>hello</Label>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and the code for listbox is here

```
<TabItem>
    <Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
        <ListBox Height="700" Width="850" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template1}">
        </ListBox>
    </Canvas>
</TabItem>
```

where am i wrong???

Comment: your ListBox doesn't have any items. It will not show anything. Make sure you bind the `ItemsSource` property to a relevant collection.

Comment: i want to display the textbox and label of the data template,how can i display that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)If you are using tabitem without tabcontrol then output is not displaying after applying itemsource to Listbox.

2) If you want to you display datatemplate(presentation of your data) then you have to bind itemsource for listbox.

**xaml code**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template1">
        <Canvas Height="40" Width="850">
            <TextBlock Height="40" Width="40" Canvas.Top="10" Foreground="Aqua"></TextBlock>
            <Label Content="{Binding State}"></Label>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
            <ListBox Height="700" Width="850" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template1}">
            </ListBox>
        </Canvas>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**c# code**

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<City> cities = new ObservableCollection<City>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Boston", State = "MA", Population = 3000000 });
        cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Los Angeles", State = "CA", Population = 7000000 });
        cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Frederick", State = "MD", Population = 65000 });
        cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Houston", State = "TX", Population = 5000000 });
        DataContext = cities;
    }
    class City
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Population { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3)You can design ListBoxItem ContentTemplate also.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListboxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas Height="40" Width="850">
                        <TextBlock Height="40" Width="40" Canvas.Top="10" Foreground="Aqua"></TextBlock>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Background="Red">
        <ListBox Height="700" Width="850" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListboxItem}">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Hello" Foreground="red"></ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Hello1"></ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Hello2"></ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```